# What will be the nature of the roots of the equation?

Tags: quadratics

What will be the nature of the roots of the equation $7x^2 – 2x + 3 = 0$

If I have two options like Imaginary and complex. Are both options are valid? Or more near answer is Imaginary.
In my book it is written as if Discriminate is less than $0$ then roots are Imaginary? So should I go with the option Imaginary?

Comment: What natures are there to choose from...??

Comment: If you have to choose from real and complex non-real, choose the second one. None of this quadratic's roots is imaginary. Both are complex non-real.

Answer (score 2):

Every quadratic equation is of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0.$

In this case, the discriminant, $\Delta=b^2-4ac=(-2)^2-4(7)(3)-80<0,$ so the roots are **complex**. (By the way, all imaginary numbers are complex.)

Here are the 3 cases in general (for a quadratic equation):

- If $\Delta>0,$ then the roots are real and distinct (e.g. $4$ and $-2$)
- If $\Delta=0$, then the roots are real and repeated (e.g. $1$ and $1$)
- If $\Delta<0$, then the roots are complex (e.g. $3 \pm i, \pm i,$ etc.), and, if the coefficients of the equation are real, then the roots of the equation appear in conjugate pairs (i.e. the roots are of the form $\alpha\pm\beta i$ where $\alpha $ and $\beta $ are real).

Incidentally, just to show, visually, which numbers belong to which set, here's a useful picture I stole from the internet:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the picture § Where did you find it ?

Comment: I found it a while ago when searching for 'number system diagram'. By the way, if, ever, you need to find a picture, right-click it and click 'search Google for this image'- it'll tell you where exactly the picture came from.